# os x user interface lectures and tutorials

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview, nsview

Can you give me links to mac os x user interface lectures , video tutorials , tutorials ?Video format will be the best but text is fit too. That will teach about NSTableView NSView and similar interface things. It should tell how to write code using Xcode for all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look a this one : "OS X Human Interface guidelines"

https://itunes.apple.com/be/book/os-x-human-interface-guidelines/id930571558?l=fr&mt=11

If it's for iOS device, you should definitely watch the course of Stanford University on iTunesU : 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-8-apps-swift/id961180099

Within XCode, you can download the documentation

[image]

Comment: thanks . I also want something related to writing program in Xcode.

Comment: new Stanford University lectures about swift. thanks looks cool. did not know about this

Comment: learn documentation is the best thing that I know now that is related to my question.

Comment: I do not understand how to download this Stanford University lectures so it can be stored in my macbook

Comment: Follow the link I gave you, the click on the blue button "View in itunes"; iTunes opens. There you have the opportunity to get the videos. You them in iTunesU on iPad, or in iTunes on your Mac.

Comment: After I open lecture in iTunes and download it  this lecture is not stored in my mac as some file with some extension like .mp4 . lecture also deletes from iTunes after some time. But I wan it to like a file with video extension that I can move anywhere I want.

Comment: I find out how to do it. I need to press "show in finder " to find this file